# Heroku running old version of seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, seed

I am having an odd Heroku problem. I successfully pushed to Heroku with a new seed file and I saw the changes go through, and this seed file just has one Item.create in it. The old seed file has 10000 creates in it. The seeding should be very quick. So far, I:

1) Made sure that I pushed from master to heroku master. I ran git push heroku master from master

2) I made sure to git add and git commit.

3) When I run heroku run rake db:seed, it still runs like this 100000 line seed file. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Did you reset the database in heroku before updating the seed file?  If not, run

```
$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

This removes the previous seed from the production database first.